# What were the numbers shouted by the dwarf woman?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-best-offer

A dwarf woman character appeared a few times in [*The Best Offer*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1924396/), reciting some numbers. During her final appearance, the numbers and their meaning were obvious. During a previous scene, she probably recited results of some arithmetic problems given to her by the audience, performing as a [mental calculator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_calculator). However, during her first scene, she was shouting numbers (initially disputed by another bar guest, who later admitted his own fault) without any context I could see. What were the numbers and their meaning or significance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numbers are :

1. the pinball machine score - and an early hint not to trust the automaton/machines.
2. the golden ratio and things ascribed to be that ratio. A major artistic/natural phenomena that is supposedly the most appealing to the human eye.
3. 227 is the number of times she has seen the woman leave the villa. When he asks them all if they've seen fake!clair she comes down and says 227.

Answer (score 3):

Early in the movie the numbers she was shouting appear to be the score of the electronic pinball machine that the guy was playing. Presumably she could calculate the score by the machine's ringing and bells. i don't know what the other numbers were.